# Efficiently convert per row values to another currency

Tags: r

Assume these two `data.frames`:

```
rates <- data.frame(Date = c("2000-01-01","2000-03-02","2000-03-25","2000-04-13"), Euro = c(1.2,1.27,1.4,1.6), Aussie = c(0.85,0.82,0.93,0.89))
toConvert <- data.frame(Date = c("2000-01-01","2000-03-02","2000-03-25","2000-04-13"), currency = c("Euro","Aussie","Euro","Aussie"),
                        Value1 = c(5,6,7,8), Value2 = c(10,15,23,85),Value3 = c(50,60,89,93))
```

Is there an efficient way of converting the `Value1`,`Value2` and `Value3` columns to dollar given the rates in the `rates` table?

Essentially, the code will have to find the rate based on the `Date` and `currency` columns in the `toConvert` table and divide `Value1`,`Value2` and `Value3` with their respective rate in the `rates` table.

I've already tried using a `for` loop which works, but takes forever. (Keep in mind these are sample tables. The actual `toConvert` table holds 100k rows of data and the `rates` table has daily data from 1990).

What I've tried:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(toConvert)) {
  rate <- as.numeric(rates[rates$Date == toConvert[i,]$Date, as.character(toConvert[1,]$currency)])
  toConvert[i,]$Value1 <- toConvert[i,]$Value1 / rate
  toConvert[i,]$Value2 <- toConvert[i,]$Value2 / rate
  toConvert[i,]$Value3 <- toConvert[i,]$Value3 / rate
}
```

Which takes A LOT of time using 100k rows.

Expected output:

```
    Date    currency   Value1    Value2    Value3
2000-01-01     Euro 4.166667  8.333333  41.66667
2000-03-02   Aussie 7.317073 18.292683  73.17073
2000-03-25     Euro 5.000000 16.428571  63.57143
2000-04-13   Aussie 8.988764 95.505618 104.49438
```

Comment: Your expected output seem incorrect as you don't really matching by currency, rather only by date. Also Rstudio is an IDE, no reason to add it to questions. It's like you would add the brand of your keyboard to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The Rstudio tag has been removed a while ago and I've updated the expected output. However the question has been answered by someone else. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you can have a look at [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) package if you have large volume of data

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(rates)
setDT(toConvert)

lrates <- melt(rates,id.vars = "Date")
toConvert[lrates,c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"):=.SD/i.value,on=.(Date,currency=variable),.SDcols = c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3")]

toConvert
#>          Date currency   Value1    Value2    Value3
#> 1: 2000-01-01     Euro 4.166667  8.333333  41.66667
#> 2: 2000-03-02   Aussie 7.317073 18.292683  73.17073
#> 3: 2000-03-25     Euro 5.000000 16.428571  63.57143
#> 4: 2000-04-13   Aussie 8.988764 95.505618 104.49438
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: this is EXACTLY. What I was looking for. Split second results and efficient! The `dplyr` alternatives are a bit slower on that many results! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the tidyverse (dplyr and tidyr) to process the whole data.frame in one go.

```r
rates <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2000-01-01","2000-03-02","2000-03-25","2000-04-13"), 
  Euro = c(1.2,1.27,1.4,1.6), 
  Aussie = c(0.85,0.82,0.93,0.89))
# Note I've added a capital C to "Currency" for consistency
toConvert <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2000-01-01","2000-03-02","2000-03-25","2000-04-13"), 
  Currency = c("Euro","Aussie","Euro","Aussie"),
  Value1 = c(5,6,7,8), Value2 = c(10,15,23,85), Value3 = c(50,60,89,93))


library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

# Gathering the rate in a tidyer format
rates <- rates %>%
  tidyr::gather(Currency, Rate, Euro, Aussie)

rates
#>         Date Currency Rate
#> 1 2000-01-01     Euro 1.20
#> 2 2000-03-02     Euro 1.27
#> 3 2000-03-25     Euro 1.40
#> 4 2000-04-13     Euro 1.60
#> 5 2000-01-01   Aussie 0.85
#> 6 2000-03-02   Aussie 0.82
#> 7 2000-03-25   Aussie 0.93
#> 8 2000-04-13   Aussie 0.89

# Add the rate with a join - this is the trick
toConvert %>%
  left_join(rates, by = c("Date", "Currency")) %>% 
# From there it is easy to convert everything at once
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), ~ .x / Rate)
#> Warning: Column `Currency` joining factor and character vector, coercing into
#> character vector
#>         Date Currency   Value1    Value2    Value3 Rate
#> 1 2000-01-01     Euro 4.166667  8.333333  41.66667 1.20
#> 2 2000-03-02   Aussie 7.317073 18.292683  73.17073 0.82
#> 3 2000-03-25     Euro 5.000000 16.428571  63.57143 1.40
#> 4 2000-04-13   Aussie 8.988764 95.505618 104.49438 0.89
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can ignore the warning when joining, or fix it by making sure `Currency` is a character vetcor and not a factor (typically using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when loading the data).

Answer (score 0):

```
#merge two files
ld <- melt(rates,id.vars = "Date")
library(data.table)
setDT(ld)
setDT(toConvert)
setnames(ld,c("variable","value"),c("currency","rate"))
s <- merge(toConvert,ld,all.x = TRUE,by=c("Date","currency"))
library(dplyr)
df <- s %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("Value")),funs(./rate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidy solution...

```
library(dplyr)

tidy_rates <- rates %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(Date), names_to = "currency", values_to = "rate")

toConvert %>% left_join(tidy_rates, by = c("Date" = "Date", "currency" = "currency")) %>% 
  mutate(
    value1_converted = Value1/rate,
    value2_converted = Value2/rate,
    value3_converted = Value3/rate
  )
```

**output**

[image]